# ensurepip causes error, even though pip is installed

Tags: python, pip, cygwin, python-venv

Not sure if I should worry or not, as pip is installed and running ok, but when I try

`python -m ensurepip`

I get the error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 188, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 147, in _get_module_details
    return _get_module_details(pkg_main_name, error)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 111, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    _SETUPTOOLS_VERSION = _get_most_recent_wheel_version("setuptools")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ensurepip/__init__.py", line 27, in _get_most_recent_wheel_version
    return str(max(_wheels[pkg], key=distutils.version.LooseVersion))
ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence
```

This seems to be causing a problem when I try to create a new virtual environment, namely:

```
python -m venv ~/.envs/proj
Error: Command '['/home/uname/.envs/proj/bin/python', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I am able to address this problem by not bootstrapping pip, i.e. by using `python -m venv --without-pip ~/.envs/proj` instead, but it feels like a problem is still lurking here...

I am running this using cygwin on windows 11

I tried to install python39-setup-tools in cygwin, and checked that other likely requirements (e.g. pip) were selected.

Comment: Installation of pip is performed through the Cygwin package manager. When you install e.g the Python39 package, you also will install Python39-pip package. You can use this system wide version of pip with your virtual environment. This is a consequence of the Cygwin and Python package managers not knowing about each other, and thus not cooperating. If you want to work with multiple python versions on cygwin, be aware that they are installed with a suffix, e.g. "3.8" or 3.9". Be sure to create the venv with, e.g. "python3.9 -m venv .venv". Then (I think), once activated, just use "python"

Comment: I think I incorrectly implied python 3.9 wasn't installed.  It does seem to be, and there is only one version.  The problem seems to be related to the pip install, rather than python maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Install the following packages:

- `python39-tox`,
- `python39-virtualenv`,
- `python39-wheel`.

*Source: see [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg170795.html) on the Cygwin mailing list.*